# Arquillian Unsatisfied dependencies for type XXXX with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I am trying to set up an Arquillian environement since one day, and I am not able to make it works, I am stuck in a loop of exceptions. Here is the one I have right now :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: fr.esisar.winewatch.test.TestUtilisateur
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.689 sec <<< FAILURE!
fr.esisar.winewatch.test.TestUtilisateur  Time elapsed: 5.681 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: testUtilisateur.war
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:201)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testUtilisateur.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"testUtilisateur.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UniteEJB with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject fr.esisar.winewatch.test.TestUtilisateur.uniteEJB
  at fr.esisar.winewatch.test.TestUtilisateur.uniteEJB(TestUtilisateur.java:0)
"}}
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.deploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:135)
    ... 96 more
```

Here, you will find my UniteEJB class (very, very simple class) :

```
package fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import fr.esisar.winewatch.entity.Unite;
import fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless.local.UniteEJBLocal;
import fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless.remote.UniteEJBRemote;

@Stateless
public class UniteEJB implements UniteEJBLocal, UniteEJBRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Unite creation(Unite u) {
        em.persist(u);
        return u;
    }

    @Override
    public void suppression(Unite u) {
        em.remove(em.merge(u));
    }

    @Override
    public Unite update(Unite u) {
        em.merge(u);
        return u;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Unite> getAllUnites() {
        List<Unite> results = em.createNamedQuery("getAllUnites",Unite.class).getResultList();
        return results;
    }

}
```

Here my test class :

```
package fr.esisar.winewatch.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import fr.esisar.winewatch.entity.Unite;
import fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless.UniteEJB;
import fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless.local.UniteEJBLocal;
import fr.esisar.winewatch.session.stateless.remote.UniteEJBRemote;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestUtilisateur {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestUtilisateur.class);

    @Deployment
    public static Archive createTestArchive() {
        System.out.println("HEY HO");
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "testUtilisateur.war")
            .addClasses(Unite.class, UniteEJB.class, UniteEJBRemote.class, UniteEJBLocal.class)
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml");

    }

    @Inject
    UniteEJB uniteEJB;

    @Test
    public void testAddNewUser() {
        System.out.println("HEY HO");
        Unite u = new Unite("Toto");
        u = uniteEJB.creation(u);
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Then, I have my arquillian.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2015, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

   <!-- Uncomment to have test archives exported to the file system for inspection -->
<!--    <engine>  -->
<!--       <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>  -->
<!--    </engine> -->

   <!-- Force the use of the Servlet 3.0 protocol with all containers, as it is the most mature -->
   <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

     <!-- Example configuration for a remote WildFly instance -->
   <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
        <!-- By default, arquillian will use the JBOSS_HOME environment variable.  Alternatively, the configuration below can be uncommented. -->
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">/home/userir/wildfly-10.0.0.Final</property>
        </configuration>
   </container>

</arquillian>
```

My test-ds.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2015, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This is an unmanaged datasource. It should be used for proofs of concept
   or testing only. It uses H2, a lightweight, in-memory, example database that
   ships with WildFly. It is not robust or scalable, is not supported,
   and should NOT be used in a production environment! -->
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
   <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference
      this in META-INF/test-persistence.xml -->
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KitchensinkQuickstartTestDS"
      pool-name="kitchensink-quickstart-test" enabled="true"
      use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:kitchensink-quickstart-test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
      <driver>h2</driver>
      <security>
         <user-name>sa</user-name>
         <password>sa</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```

My test-persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2015, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- We use a different datasource for tests, so as to not overwrite
         production data. This is an unmanaged data source, backed by H2, an in memory
         database. Production applications should use a managed datasource. -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/test-ds.xml,
         you can find it in the source at src/test/resources/test-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KitchensinkQuickstartTestDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and here is my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.esisar.winewatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>WineWatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <wildfly.server.hostname>127.0.0.1</wildfly.server.hostname>
        <wildfly.server.port>9990</wildfly.server.port>
        <wildfly.server.user>admin</wildfly.server.user>
        <wildfly.server.password>admin</wildfly.server.password>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-EDR2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final-redhat-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink</artifactId>
            <version> 2.7.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${wildfly.server.hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly.server.port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly.server.user}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly.server.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
     <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote
                WildFly instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have enable the arq-wildfly-remote profile in maven, but still I am note able to make my test work ... Do you have any clues pleases ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using servlet protocol instead. Default one in WildFly is JMX. Even though it's suitable for testing WildFly code itself, for regular JavaEE applications it's not really feasible. Might related to it.

Please add following to your `arquillian.xml`:

```
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>
```

And following test dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the JBOSS_HOME variable and switching out on the right maven profile. Thanks for the response ! Hope it will help someone else.